# Convert array in array to string

Tags: php, arrays

I wonder if there's easy way to convert array which is in another array to string and keep it in that array ? The array which is inside array always consists of only 1 key. This is array that I have now:

```
array(6) {
  ["miestas"]=>
  string(2) "CC"
  ["checkbox"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["kiekis"]=>
  string(5) "Three"
}
```

And this is the result what I want to get:

```
array(6) {
  ["miestas"]=>
  string(2) "CC"
  ["checkbox"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["kiekis"]=>
  string(5) "Three"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [type cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the value

```
$data['checkbox'] = (string) $data['checkbox'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Read this: http://php.net/array

Use this: `$array['checkbox'] = $array['checkbox'][0];`

Answer (score 1):

[**array_replace**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

```
$replacement = array('checkbox' => 1); 

$outputYouWant = array_replace($yourArray, $replacement);

print_r($outputYouWant);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loops through the input array and checks if `value` is an array using `is_array` function.  Pushes `value` array's value at index zero if an array otherwise pushes `value` to the result array.

```
$input = array('miestas' => 'CC', 'checkbox' => array("1"), 'kiekis' => 'Three');

$result = array();
foreach($input as $key=>$value) {
    $result[$key] = is_array($value) ? $value[0] : $value;  
}

// var_dump($result);
```